# How to open browser with NTLM auth

Tags: go

I'm trying emulate browser, open intranet url and get status code 401. How to open url with ntl auth or login, pass?
Thanks

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/headzoo/surf.v1"
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
    bow := surf.NewBrowser()
    bow.AddRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html")
    bow.AddRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf8")
    err := bow.Open(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(bow.StatusCode())
}
```

Comment: Do you _need_ to emulate browser or would it suffice to merely to a HTTP request to a resource in the intranet?

Comment: Need emulate browser

Comment: OK, a couple more questions: 1) Was "ntl" in your question meant to indicate "NTLM"? 2) What happens when you navigate that `url` "the normal way"—using a browser on your desktop? Does the server authenticate you "transparently"—without asking anything,—or does it post a pop-up dialogue asking you to enter the user name and a password? Or does _the site page_ display some sort of login form asking you to provide your credentials?

Comment: (As you can see, your question does not fit for the StackOverflow format; it's strictly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. It's better to ask such questions on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) or, say, on [`r/golang`](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang) or [other venues](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community) suitable for such free-form questions implying multiple back-and-forth conversations.)

Comment: 1. Oh sorry, ntl is NTLM 2. Server authenticate me "transparently"

Answer (score 0):

> How to open url with ntl auth or login, pass? Thanks 
>   1. Oh sorry, ntl is NTLM 2. Server authenticate me "transparently"

I will assume the user is authenticated against an AD domain.

First - the [NTLM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236621.aspx) protocol is not so simple as e.g. basic authentication. It is a multiple-step protocol involving some system/user specific data. Client and server need to exchange a few challenge/answer data in a Negotiation HTTP header.

I'd suggest to use an out-of-box library; e.g [go-ntlmssp](https://github.com/Azure/go-ntlmssp) or [gokrb5](https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5).

Note: when using SPNEGO (NTLM over HTTP) authentication, depending on the AD settings, if a user/service principal has too many roles, the Negotiation HTTP header may get VERY large. If you have any default limit for HTTP headers, you may watch if you don't reach the limit.